# Title Parameter Double-Encoded in "How to Ask" Screen's Search Box

Tags: bug, asking-questions

If a title is provided for the "How to Ask" screen, it will be double-encoded in the search box.

> ## [`/questions/ask/advice?title=This'%20a%20test.`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice?title=This%27%20a%20test.)
>
> [image]